# Search opposite values in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I initially began this project in VBA, however, very quickly learnt that VBA is inefficient and have attempted to replicate my code into SQL.

I have attempted to look through all rows and group together (ideally at the top of the data/ a new table) all amounts which have a corresponding negative amount and have the same account code.

My SQL knowledge is currently non existent so any advise or links to trainings are welcomed. Also any assistance on how i may script this within SQL will be welcomed

**Initial Data input**

The data is in excel, 100k+ rows, column A labelled [Account Code], column i labelled [Amount].

**Desired output**

Ideally all grouped amounts (grouped with corresponding negatives i.e. +1000 is grouped with a row with amount -1000) and equal account codes either at the top of the data or in a separate table.

**VBA Code**

```vb
'n = total rows
n = Range("A8").End(xlDown).Row

'l= total number of positives
l = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(8, 9), Cells(n, 9)), ">0") + 1

CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
For i = 8 To l
    For j = l + 1 To n
        If Range("i" & i) = -Range("i" & j) Then
            If Range("a" & i) = Range("a" & j) Then
                Worksheets("Ledger Extract").Range(i & ":" & i).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(CurrentRow & ":" & CurrentRow)

                CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1

                Worksheets("Ledger Extract").Range(j & ":" & j).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & CurrentRow)

                CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

[image]

**MY SQL Progress**

```sql
SELECT [Account Code], COUNT(*) Occurence, SUM([Amount]) TotalAmount
FROM Table
GROUP BY [Account Code]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

So far this manages to collate all the occurences where there are multiple accounts, but does not solve my query of only collating the opposite amounts.

Comment: Please post your entities structure and the expected output so we can help.

Comment: Please can you clarify what you mean by entity structure? is this the initial data input?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results as *text tables* in the question.

Comment: added - essentially we have the initial data with loads of account codes and amounts. The final output should be a table with all matching amounts (i.e. the sum of the two amounts is 0) at the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting all records that have a match you can use

```
SELECT      * 
FROM        Table T1
WHERE EXISTS
 ( SELECT * FROM Table AS T2
   WHERE t1.[Account Code] = T2.[Account Code]
   AND   t1.Amount = -t2.Amount
 ) 
 ORDER BY [Account Code], ABS(Amount)
```

And for getting all records that doesnt have a match you can use the following query.

```
SELECT      * 
FROM        Table T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 ( SELECT * FROM Table AS T2
   WHERE t1.[Account Code] = T2.[Account Code]
   AND   t1.Amount = -t2.Amount
 ) 
 ORDER BY [Account Code], ABS(Amount)
```

Comment: just for my understanding can you confirm whether the following is correct for the first script above. 

You set all the data and label it as T1. 

You then set a new table labelled T2 as all the data again. 

So at this point T1 and T2 are the same data tables. 

You are then applying the two criteria and ordering by account code and absolute amounts

Comment: I did that example following the last example that you added to the post, 'Table' is just a generic name, replace it with the tablename where you have the actual data, T1 and T2 are aliases. T1 Contains all the data and T2 contains only the rows that have a pair. The rest that you assume is correct.

Comment: Ahhh i see, so T2 is the table where the two criteria have been met! I believe this makes sense and so does the structure in script! Thank you

Comment: You can check the example here and play around with it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/103477